# Flutter: No named parameter with the name 'home'

Tags: flutter

I've seen the other posts and none of them was helpful.
I've freshly Installed Android Studio and Flutter, I've been following a tutorial on Youtube and I've used the exact code the tutorial have. It worked in the video, but not on my PC.

It will always say that "home" is not named parameter!

flutter doctor say that everything is ok.

Can you help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main () {
  runApp (new Material (
     color: Colors.amber,
     home: Textclass(),
   ));
}

class Textclass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center (
      child: new Text (
        "Ahmad", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use **MaterialApp** instead of **Material**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MaterialApp() instead of Material()

```
void main () {
  runApp (new MaterialApp (
     color: Colors.amber,
     home: Textclass(),
   ));
}
```

MaterialApp has the property "home".